# Facebook pulled its Messenger for Desktop link?

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-chat

Did Facebook remove the link to download Messnger for Windows from their site? Their help pages point here https://www.facebook.com/about/messenger but this page only shows the mobile app for iPhone, Android and BlackBerry and nothing for the desktop.

Comment: Wow. They should have updated the help pages so that it is not misleading. And yeah, since you have answered my question, can you put it as an answer please?

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: There is no app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) said (he deleted his comment now), the app has been pulled by Facebook.